# UNIX - Is there any way to send a CAT output through servers?

Tags: cat

I'm relatively new on IT and was wondering how to do this, assuming its possible.

I don't have write permission on the server but i can get files from it using the fttget command.

Sometimes i have to use grep/uniq/(etc) on several files and it'd be usefull to have the output on a file i can download and access instead of having to copy it from the console.

I dont know if i can mix fttget with grep for example or using cat with fttput and havent found it online yet...

Versions:

```
Linux access 20 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 6 18:30:54 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux 

Linux xxx.xxx.com 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 13 18:24:36 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I apprecciate any help, and i'm sorry for any mistakes (non native english here)

Comment: Do you really mean `fttget` and `fttpput` or is that supposed to be `ftpget` and `ftpput`?

Comment: Yeah, really fttget like in fttget server1 path/file .

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a standard command. Perhaps it's been written by your local IT service.

Comment: Since this `fttget` appears to be a site-specific command, maybe just try adding pipeline commands on the end. Try something like `fttget server1 path/file | grep phrase` or `fttget server1 path/file >outputfile`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about a locally-written tool